# PHP Assocative array Reordering

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays and I want to combine them into a single array while maintain the assocative name

Here is a example

```
a$["ln"]=array(1,2);
b$["ids"]=array(11,22);
```

so if I do a print_r I get

```
[ln] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[ids] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 22
    )
```

Now what I want to do is to combine them together into the below.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [ln] => 1
        [ids] => 11
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ls] => 2
        [ids] => 22
    )
```

My curent code for this is

```
$data = array(
    "ln"=>array(1,2),
    "ids"=>array(11,22)
)

for ($x = 0; $x < count($data["ln"]); $x++) {
    $vals[$x]["ln"]=$data["ln"][$x];
    $vals[$x]["ids"]=$data["ids"][$x];
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Looping is the fastest way. Are you looking for an illegible code-golfed one-liner? It will have the overhead of calling functions and will be in fact, slower...

Comment: Here: `print_r(array_map(function($a, $b){ return array('ln'=>$a,'ids'=>$b);}, $a['ln'], $b['ids']));`

Comment: I was mainly trying to find a better, faster way of doing this that maybe i hadn't thought of

Comment: "Better" is subjective and "faster" is measurable in programming. Without knowing what you've attempted how could I possibly discern something that's better or faster? Are you having performance issues such as speed or memory consumption? Maybe a small tweak could fix it. Is your code long and awkward? Well I cannot suggest improvement unless I see it. If you're just polling "How would you achieve this?" then your question is utterly off-topic.

Comment: Your code above is invalid Php.

Answer (score 0):

You can foreach in a foreach:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'ln' => [1,2],
    'ids'=> [11,22]
];

foreach($data as $i => $j) {
    foreach($j as $k => $l) {
        $result[$k][$i] = $l;
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ln' => 1,
    'ids' => 11,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ln' => 2,
    'ids' => 22,
  ),
)
```